# jQuery scroll function to start at specific height

Tags: jquery, css, scroll, css-transitions

This is actually two questions:

1. Why is the 1s transition from `display:none;` to `display:block;` not working?
2. How can I make this scroll function only take place after `scrolling 200px` from the top, i.e. after having scrolled past the "red box"?

Any help is much appreciated, thanks a lot!

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
    $('#menu').css('display', 'block');
    clearTimeout($.data(this, 'scrollTimer'));
    $.data(this, 'scrollTimer', setTimeout(function() {
       $('#menu').css('display', 'none');
    }, 1500));
});
```

```css
html {
   padding:0;margin:0;
}
body {
    height:2000px
}
#redBox{ 
    height:200px;
    width:100%;
    background:red;
    float:left;
    color:white;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:8em;
    font-size:1.2em;
}
#menu {
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    background: navy;
    opacity: .5;
    color:white;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:8em;
    font-size:1.2em; 
    display: none;
    -webkit-transition:all 1s;
    transition:all 1s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="redBox">scroll function should start below this box (height: 200px)</div>
<div id="menu">scroll menu</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) You can use jQuery `fadeIn` and `fadeOut`

2) Or

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (scrollTop > 200) {
        $('#menu').fadeIn('slow');
        clearTimeout($.data(this, 'scrollTimer'));
        $.data(this, 'scrollTimer', setTimeout(function () {
            $('#menu').fadeOut('slow');
        }, 1500));
    }else{
        clearTimeout($.data(this, 'scrollTimer'));
        $('#menu').fadeOut('slow');
    }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/uqpamt4z/

Comment: thanks a lot, this works great, but i can't get the fadeIn / fadeOut to work! I tried like this:
`code`$(window).scroll(function() {
 var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop(); //get the current scroll value
    if (scrollTop > 200) { // if it's greater than 200px from top
 $('#menu').fadeIn('slow');
 clearTimeout($.data(this, 'scrollTimer'));
 $.data(this, 'scrollTimer', setTimeout(function() {
  $('#menu').fadeOut('slow');
 }, 1500));
 }
});`code`

Answer (score 1):

Answer to 1. Its not possible to animate the 'display' property as it needs to be an numeric value and its not rendered by the browser, when animating with opacity its usually better to use visibilty:hidden/visible but this will probably mean you will need to toggle the z-index of the element so the hidden element is not clickable

Answer to 2.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var ScrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (ScrollTop > 200) {
      ....
    }

});
```

Note: when using the scroll event you can get into all sorts of performance issues, i.e. you should unbind the scroll event when not being used and ideally throttle the amount of times the scroll event occurs a second, unless your doing something very simple it maybe better to use a plugin i.e. jQuery Waypoints

Answer (score 0):

CSS (Point 1):

```
html{
    padding:0;margin:0;
}
body{
    height:2000px
}
#redBox{
    height:200px;
    width:100%;
    background:red;
    float:left;
    color:white;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:8em;
    font-size:1.2em;
}
#menu {
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    background: navy;
    color:white;text-align:center;line-height:8em;font-size:1.2em;  
    display: none;
}
```

Javascript (Point 2):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var headerTop = $('body').offset().top;
        var headerBottom = headerTop + 200; 
        $(window).scroll(function () {
            var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop(); 
            if (scrollTop > headerBottom) {
                if (($("#menu").is(":visible") === false)) {
                    $('#menu').fadeIn('slow');
                }
            } else {
                if ($("#menu").is(":visible")) {
                    $('#menu').fadeOut('fast');
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

Already tested. Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

I think that's what you want:

```
var startAfter = 200,
menuIsVisible = false;

$(window).scroll(function() {

if($(document).scrollTop() > startAfter && !menuIsVisible) {
    $("#menu").fadeIn(1000, function(){
        menuIsVisible = true;
    });
}
else if ($(document).scrollTop() <= startAfter && menuIsVisible) {
    $("#menu").fadeOut(1000, function(){
        menuIsVisible = false;
    });
}
```

});

[Check this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7n2291f8/1/)